# Complex SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine an 1:N relationship among tables t_parent and t_child. The PK of the parent table t_parent is requestid and of course this is the FK for t_child. Also, t_child has another field called usermail which contains en email address. I want to write a SELECT statement which will return for **every** record of t_parent:

1)requestid (easy)

2)the **number** of records in t_child assosiated with the corresponding requestid (by using count, I am getting only one row as output even if the records of t_parent are more)

3)the emails from field usermail of the associated (with current requestid) records of t_child, all together combined in a **string**.

Is the above SELECT possible?

Thank you

Comment: My imagination lets me down, can you post your schema (maybe table structure, data, desired result)?

Comment: Is your poor imagination reason for downvoting?

Comment: Are you familiar with presumption of innocence? _P.S. I didn't vote your question down (nor up, anticipating other possible questions)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t_parent.id, COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(t_child.usermail)
FROM t_parent
LEFT JOIN t_child
ON t_parent.id = t_child.parent_id
GROUP BY t_parent.id
```

Comment: You are welcome, but you really should put more technical details in you question next time. Such as table structure, data samples and expected result.